# SharePoint 2010 Backup Restoration Metadata Tags Issue

Tags: backup, restore, tagging

I am facing problem in my SharePoint 2010 environment for the backup-restoration of site collection backup's. I have some metadata fields in my list/libraries. whenever I do restore the backup on new virtual machine having all the tags already created in metadata service application, the web parts I have configured using metadata tags stop's working and when I go to list/libraries where I have associated these tags to some list items/documents they appear in red color.

Now when I again edit these list items/documents and again configure web parts with these tags they works fine.

I want these tags should be associated with the backup restoration when they are already created, documents and list items in my libraries are increasing by numbers so its not possible to edit web parts and documents libraries/list each time I do backup restore.

Comment: Hello. FYI, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Have a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374876/sharepoint2010-restore-does-not-restore-the-tags/8384702#8384702

Comment: @Maks thnx for you reply can you tell me the process how can I attach  Metadata Service database to new virtual machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restore the Managed Metadata SQL database to your test environment.  Create a new Managed Metadata Service Application in your test environment using the same name of the database you restored.

You may need to give your service account permissions to the MM SQL db prior to creating the SA.

Comment: thnx, @Trevor Seward